# I have a looping job but with in the looping I want to click the command button using excel vba is this possible

Tags: excel, vba

I have a looping job but with in the looping I want to click the command button using excel vba is this possible?

```
Sub workbook_open()
Dim c As Boolean
Dim choice As Range
Dim counter As Integer
Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "SHOW.TOOLBAR(""Riboon"",true)"
Sheets("psr").Activate

Do
    If choice = ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("psrnew")).Select Then
        psrnew_reqinfo.Show
        c = False
    Else
        counter = counter + 1
        Range("A1").Value = counter
        'Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"))
   End If
Loop Until c = True
End Sub
```

Comment: `If choice = ....Select then` that code is wrong. What are you trying to do with that line?

Comment: i want to disrupt or end the looping when the activex command button is press.

Answer (score 0):

The question here is really about interrupting execution of your code and passing control to your operating system to process the message queue (where your button click event will be patiently waiting). The function to do this is `DoEvents` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/doevents-function).

How often you call `DoEvents` is entirely up to you. Pretty obviously, the more you call it (ie interrupt your own code), the slower your routine will be. There are other issues associated with `DoEvents` but the documentation should point you in the right direction.

As an example for your scenario, you'd need three routines: one handling the button click (if it's an ActiveX button, I've presumed its code behind the Sheet containing your button), one in your module to consume the click event (in the sample code, it changes a module-level flag to False), and another in your module to run the loop (which ends if the flag is False). So...

**Module code**

```
Option Explicit

Private mLeaveLoop As Boolean

Public Sub Main()
    Const LIMIT As Long = 1000000
    Dim counter As Long

    mLeaveLoop = False
    counter = 1
    Do
        counter = counter + 1
        DoEvents
        If counter = LIMIT Then Exit Do 'emergency exit to avoid infinite loop
    Loop Until mLeaveLoop

    Debug.Print "Stopped at " & counter
End Sub

Public Sub ConsumeButtonClick()
    mLeaveLoop = True
End Sub
```

**And your Sheet code**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    ConsumeButtonClick
End Sub
```